# how to find (grep) paragraph start with word and ending with other word and ignore new line?

Tags: grep, find, newlines

I want to find a paragraph is a list of files.
For example an SQL statement which looks like:

```
upadte b_table
set number = 100014
where id in (
            select number_desc from t_table
            where id > 100);
```

How should I ignore enter/new lines?

I need to find/print a paragraph which starts with "update" and finishes with the first occurrence of `;`

Answer (score 3):

grep is a bit tricky with newlines, but you could try something with awk:

```
awk '/update/,/;/' < filename.sql
```

Comment: How would you deal with a file containing multiple update statements?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - The above statement should print all statements with the matching start and stop parts. I assume that's what is required.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by barryj's concise awk solution:

```
perl -ne 'print if /update/../;/' *.sql
```

If the update statements are contained in (empty-line delimited) paragraphs:

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if /update.*?;/' *.sql
```

-- from http://uselessuseofcat.com/?p=381

Otherwise, this prints filenames and update statements:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{undef $/}; print "$ARGV\t$.\t$1\n" if m/(update.*?;)/mg' *.sql
```

-- from http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5087/multi-line-grep

(untested - caveat emptor)

Comment: ok - i did used grep with regexp like this:

Answer (score 0):

I used grep like this:

```
grep -ihRP  '^(update|( )* update) .* [^;]*;'
```

Comment: using grep with perl engine other wise regexp not works "good" in bash and prints everything except ; after the word "update" or "    update" until first appearance of ;